# Passing data to a Polymer element

Tags: dart, polymer

When working with Web UI I could pass data to a component like this:

```
<my-element" name="{{someName}}"></my-element>
```

How do I pass data to a Polymer element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass data to a Polymer element, but there is a little bit more detail involved.  Imagine the element with a single field, `name`:

```dart
// In element.dart.
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag("my-element")
class MyElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
   @observable String name;
}
```

And here is the accompanying html:

```dart
// In element.html.
<polymer-element name='my-element' attributes="name">
  <template>
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Note the `attributes="name"` part. That configures things so that the element can be passed the name attribute when it is created (you can pass in multiple attributes by separating them with a comma if your element needs it).

When creating the element, wrap it in a `<template>` tag that is bound to the values you want to pass to it:

```dart
// In index.html.
<template id='name1' bind>
  <my-element name="{{}}"></my-element>
</template>

<template id='name2' bind>
  <my-element name="{{}}"></my-element>
</template>
```

Each `<template>` gets bound to a separate value (we'll get to that in a second). When creating the element, you can get that value using `{{}}` syntax.

The data can be bound to the template in the following manner:

```dart
// In index.dart.
void main() {
  query('#name1').model ='Bob';
  query('#name2').model ='Rohan';
}
```

This way, the first `<my-element>` is created with the name 'Bob', and the second `<my-element>` is created with the name 'Rohan'.

Comment: With the current Polymer, shouldn't we be using `@piblished` instead of `@observable` on a property that corresponds to an externally settable attribute?

Comment: Also, how do I assign to the model if my-element has multiple attributes? `querySelector('#name1').model = ['Rob', 34]` or `querySelector('#name1').model = {name: 'Rob', age: 34}` or...?

Comment: And finally, what's the main advantage of using `template bind` as opposed to this: `<my-element id='name1'></...>`, and then in .dart: `(querySelector('#name1') as MyElement).name = 'Rob'`? Is it the fact that I don't have to import my_element.dart and downcast to MyElement?