# PolymerElement Constructor

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to **change the standard constructor to add myConstructor**.

Based on the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997989/pass-parameters-to-dart-polymer-element) I coded the following statements:

```dart
@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  factory MainApp.custom() {
    MainApp = new Element.tag('main-app');
    myConstructor();
  }
MainApp.created() : super.created();
void myConstructor() {
    print("myConstructor Started");
  }
```

Unfortunately the Editor shows some problems:
The Statement `MainApp = new Element.tag('main-app')` shows the error:
`A Value of Type 'Element' cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'Type'.`

The Statement *myConstructor()* shows the Error:
 "Instance members cannot be accessed from a factory constructor"

anyone has a suggestion how I can solve the errors?

**EDIT**:
The current code is looking like following:

```dart
@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  @observable int counter = 0;


      factory MainApp.custom() {
    MainApp mainApp = new Element.tag('main-app');
    mainApp.myConstructor();
    return mainApp;
  }

  /// Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
  MainApp.created() : super.created();

MainApp ma = new MainApp.custom();

  void myConstructor() {
    print("myConstructor Started");
    counter = 1;
  }
```

The following error is showing up:

```dart
Exception: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'MainApp' of 'mainApp'.
  MainApp.MainApp.custom    
  MainApp.MainApp.created
```

**EDIT Version 2:**

```dart
@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {

  Controller controller = new Controller();

  @observable int counter = myConstructor();
  @observable int totalGlypto = 0;

  /// Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
  MainApp.created() : super.created();


    static int myConstructor() {
    print("myConstructor Started");
    return controller.getTotal();
  }

  void setupCheckIn(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    print("Setup started");
    controller.checkInGlypto();
    counter = controller.getTotal();
  }

  void resetCheckIn(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    print("reset started");
  }

  void loadCheckIn(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    print("load started");
    controller.loadData();
    counter = controller.getTotal();
  }


}
```

the code can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/kenparker/Glypto.git)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the class `MainApp` like a variable. Change the following line

```dart
MainApp = new Element.tag('main-app');
```

to either

```dart
MainApp mainApp = new Element.tag('main-app');
```

or

```dart
var mainApp = new Element.tag('main-app');
```

Comment: I have changed the code as suggested: <br/><code>factory MainApp.custom() {
    MainApp mainApp = new Element.tag('main-app');
    mainApp.myConstructor();} void myConstructor() {
    print("myConstructor Started");}</code> <br/>but it seems myConstructor() is not executed.

Comment: And, does it work as expected? You should return the value from the constructor as well. Otherwise there is no point in creating such a factory constructor.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, I have posted the new code under EDIT above. It looks like the myConstructor is not called. Thanks

Comment: Do you call `new MainApp. custom()` anywhere? (Your factory constructor still doesn't return the instance.)

Comment: I have now added the return instance and called the constructor (see the new code under EDIT) but there is still a problem with new MainApp.customer() as I should pass a parameter.

Comment: What is that parameter for? Doesn't seem to make sense there.

Comment: I agree so I have removed the parameter from the factory but then an Exception is occurring (see code above)

Comment: `MainApp ma = new MainApp.custom();` is outside of any function/method - this can't work, how do you actually call this in your code.

Comment: If you call this from main you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20982658/217408

Comment: I have pushed the whole code to GitHub the link is above. I'm going to look at your link now

Comment: The way you built your app you don't even need a custom constructor.  Why do you want to add one anyway. I figured `MainApp ma = new MainApp.custom();` is a field but this is redundant within your element because it is the same as `this`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68142/discussion-between-ken-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Sorry, I have to leave. Tomorrow I'll have time again.

Comment: I have added a Getter to the code and it seems to work, I do not know exactly why but it seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

ok, now I think I found an answer, the key is the following code:

```
@observable int get counter => myConstructor();
```